# Automate paragraphs in a post page to have a unique anchor link

Tags: plugins

I have this idea for linking to a paragraph within a post. It would work by every paragraph within `the_content()` on post pages having an anchor tag automatically placed before it, like this: `<a href="#p1"></a>` where '1' is the first paragraph and it would increment for every subsequent paragraph, eg p2, p3, p4...

Anyone fancy taking a shot at it would be great? Maybe something in functions.php?

Thanks.

Comment: I've created a rudimentary plugin that does this job, here: http://www.robertsharp.co.uk/paragraph-level-ids/ Would love to know what everyone thinks, and welcome any improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should really be `<a name="p1">` around the paragraphs with link to the paragraphs being `<a href="#p1">`.

If that is what you are trying to accomplish ( what used to be called a named anchors ), that technique is not valid in HTML 5. You can instead link to any `id` in the page, so with that in mind.

```
$count = 0;
function auto_id_p_cb($matches) {
  var_dump($matches);
  global $count;
  $count++;
  $ret = '<p id="p_'.$count.'"';
  if (!empty($matches[1])) $ret .= $matches[1];
  $ret .= '>';
  return $ret;
}
function auto_id_p($content){
  $content = preg_replace_callback('/<p([^>]*)>/','auto_id_p_cb',$content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','auto_id_p',1000);
```

Minimally tested but it does preserve existing attributes in the `<p>` tags. I am sure it would produce a duplicate `id` if one already existed in the `<p>` so watch that. Think of it more as "proof of concept".

If you do still what to do it with actual `<a>` tags, you should be able to adapt that.

Comment: Thanks for this. The ID on the <p> is a better solution. I might adapt the anchor to be p_<postID>_<count> so there's a unique id for every <p> across the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Jquery.

Jquery would look like this:

```
var i = 0;
$('.entry p').each(function(){
   i++;
   $(this).attr('id', 'p'+i); //labels the paragraph tags with unique ids.
   $('.entry-anchors').append('<a href="#p'+i+'">'+i+'</a>');

});
```

Then either add a `<div class="entry-anchors"></div>` wherever you want those links to appear within your template. Or you could even add it dynamically via Jquery with something like:

```
$('.entry').before('<div class="entry-anchors"></div>');
```

You would want to make sure that you declare the "entry-anchors" div before assigning values to it in jquery of course.

Comment: Thanks. I had similar in jQuery myself, but @s_ha_dum's input below looks more like what I'm after.